# Waiting time for the Certificate of Application for non-EU residence card application

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration

I sent my non-EU direct family member application to the Home office one week ago. I know I have to wait around 6 months before I can get the actual residence card. As far as I know, the Home office issues a certificate that that states whether I am allowed to live and work legally in the UK. How long does one normally wait before getting this certificate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally within three weeks of your completed biometric enrollment. [EEA residence COA.](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/eea-residence-card-applications-certificates-of-application/eea-residence-card-applications-certificates-of-application)